# Solving a system of equations for $x, y,$ and $T$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

While solving a computer science question, I got a system of equations$$\begin{cases}x^2+(100-y)^2=\frac TA\\(100+x)^2+(100+y)^2=\frac TB\\(100-x)^2+(100+y)^2=\frac TC\end{cases}$$

However, I'm having difficulty solving the equation. $A, B, C$ are constants and we need to find $x, y, T$. I tried subtracting the third equation from the second equation, but still had difficulty with eliminating the extra $T$ variable.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Moo Hm... this was a question from a competition. I'm fairly certain there is an easier or nicer solution. I will go over my work.

Comment: I would give it a try geometrically. The three equations represent three circles centered respectively at $(0,100), (-100,-100),(100,-100).$ A necessary condition to have at least an intersection between the second and the third circle is that, for example, $T/B \geq 100^2$. When their intersection is not empty, they intersect each other at two points on the same vertical line $x=L$. To get a solution of the system, the third circle should pass through one of those points found. This is just a suggestion on how to proceed, I am not sure if it is doable. Can you go on from here?

Answer (score 0):

Plugging $$(100+y)^2=\frac{T}{C}-(100-x)^2$$ in the second equation we get
$$(100+x)^2-(100-x)^2=\frac{T}{B}-\frac{T}{C}$$
we get by Using the binomial formulas

$$400x=\frac{T}{B}-\frac{T}{C}$$
Can you proceed?
For $T$ we get
$$T=800\,{\frac {ABC}{AB+AC-2\,BC} \left( 50\,{\frac {8\,{A}^{2}BC-8\,{B
}^{2}{C}^{2}+\sqrt {-25\,{A}^{4}{B}^{4}+50\,{A}^{4}{B}^{2}{C}^{2}-25\,
{A}^{4}{C}^{4}+140\,{A}^{3}{B}^{4}C+20\,{A}^{3}{B}^{3}{C}^{2}+20\,{A}^
{3}{B}^{2}{C}^{3}+140\,{A}^{3}B{C}^{4}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{4}{C}^{2}-152
\,{A}^{2}{B}^{3}{C}^{3}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}{C}^{4}+224\,A{B}^{4}{C}^{3
}+224\,A{B}^{3}{C}^{4}-64\,{B}^{4}{C}^{4}}}{5\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}-6\,{A}^{
2}BC+5\,{A}^{2}{C}^{2}-4\,A{B}^{2}C-4\,{C}^{2}AB+4\,{B}^{2}{C}^{2}}}+
25 \right) }
$$

and for $x$

$$x=-2\,{\frac {A}{AB+AC-2\,BC} \left( 50\,{\frac {B \left( 8\,{A}^{2}BC
-8\,{B}^{2}{C}^{2}+\sqrt {-25\,{A}^{4}{B}^{4}+50\,{A}^{4}{B}^{2}{C}^{2
}-25\,{A}^{4}{C}^{4}+140\,{A}^{3}{B}^{4}C+20\,{A}^{3}{B}^{3}{C}^{2}+20
\,{A}^{3}{B}^{2}{C}^{3}+140\,{A}^{3}B{C}^{4}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{4}{C}^{2
}-152\,{A}^{2}{B}^{3}{C}^{3}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}{C}^{4}+224\,A{B}^{4}{
C}^{3}+224\,A{B}^{3}{C}^{4}-64\,{B}^{4}{C}^{4}} \right) }{5\,{A}^{2}{B
}^{2}-6\,{A}^{2}BC+5\,{A}^{2}{C}^{2}-4\,A{B}^{2}C-4\,{C}^{2}AB+4\,{B}^
{2}{C}^{2}}}-50\,{\frac {C \left( 8\,{A}^{2}BC-8\,{B}^{2}{C}^{2}+
\sqrt {-25\,{A}^{4}{B}^{4}+50\,{A}^{4}{B}^{2}{C}^{2}-25\,{A}^{4}{C}^{4
}+140\,{A}^{3}{B}^{4}C+20\,{A}^{3}{B}^{3}{C}^{2}+20\,{A}^{3}{B}^{2}{C}
^{3}+140\,{A}^{3}B{C}^{4}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{4}{C}^{2}-152\,{A}^{2}{B}^{
3}{C}^{3}-276\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}{C}^{4}+224\,A{B}^{4}{C}^{3}+224\,A{B}^{3
}{C}^{4}-64\,{B}^{4}{C}^{4}} \right) }{5\,{A}^{2}{B}^{2}-6\,{A}^{2}BC+
5\,{A}^{2}{C}^{2}-4\,A{B}^{2}C-4\,{C}^{2}AB+4\,{B}^{2}{C}^{2}}}+25\,B-
25\,C \right) }
$$

Comment: That's exactly what we did.